# HTML Content doesnt render in popover content in fullcalendar

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, fullcalendar

I am following a this codepen [Here](https://codepen.io/IsmiKin/pen/WbOeGw) to implement popover in my fullcalendar. But the html does not render in popover.content. Instead it just displays it as string. Here is my implementation.

```
 function GenerateCalender(events) {
            $('#calender').fullCalendar('destroy');
            $('#calender').fullCalendar({
                contentHeight: 400,
                defaultDate: new Date(),
                timeFormat: 'h(:mm)a',
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next today',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: 'month,basicWeek,basicDay,agenda'
                },
                eventLimit: true,
                eventColor: '#378006',
                events: event_array,
                eventRender: function (calEvent, $el) {
                    $el.popover({
                        title: calEvent.title,
                        content: "<div><b>Example popover</b> - content</div>",
                        start: calEvent.start,
                        end: calEvent.end,
                        trigger: "hover",
                        placement: "top",
                        container: "body"
                    });
                }
            })
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty sure this will have been asked before, but you can simply set the option

```
html: true
```

in your popover options to have your content rendered as HTML.

See the [documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#options) for details.

Comment: It worked. Thank you. Yes it must have been asked before, but i wasnt able to find it with my search technique.

Comment: No problem. But did you not look at the documentation page either? That should have been pretty easy to find.

Comment: No i did not. Somehow i was just going through example code and the thought never occurred to me. Next time the first place i am looking is the documentation.